# Java's "TODO"s appear in overview ruler but JS's not?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, configuration, annotations

How do I make the "TODO" tags (`// TODO: blah...`) appear in the overview ruler for JS in Eclipse?

In Java they are visible, but for JS not.

They are obviously in the "Task Tags" list, and the "Overview ruler" is checked for "Tasks" under "Annotations".

Comment: Before anyone tries to close this as off topic, *software tools commonly used by programmers* are **on-topic** on SO per [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Java, this is handled by the corresponding builder, the "JavaScript Validator" builder (not to be confused with the "Client-Side JavaScript Validator"), operating on the project's JavaScript Include Path.  If it's not enabled, the file's not on the include path, or you're not built, it won't show.  This all assumes you're using WTP's JavaScript Developer Tools and not something from Aptana or MyEclipse.

Comment: I don't understand from your answer what should I do, then. I have two Eclipses (both Indigo): J2EE version and one for Android development. In the J2EE the JS's TODOs appear on the overview, but in the Android Eclipse they don't

Comment: Does the Android one even have the JavaScript tools installed?  If not, add them.  Then go to your project's Configure context menu and add JavaScript support to the project.

Comment: For newbies like me this is the complete answer: right click on the project in "Project Explorer": Properties -> "Project Facets" -> check "JavaScript"

Answer (score 0):

For newbies like me & future reference: here is the complete answer: right click on the project in "Project Explorer": **Properties** -> **Project Facets** -> check the **JavaScript** check-box.

Thanks @nitind and [Konstantin Komissarchik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4976747/587467) for directing me to the right path.